# TSQL break loop when @@ROWCOUNT = 0

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I have insert statements (simplified) in a SPROC like the following

```
SET ROWCOUNT 100

WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition
  -- EDIT: Realized forgot to include this following vital line that is causing issue
  SET @var = @var + @@ROWCOUNT    

  -- @@ROWCOUNT now takes on a value of 1, which will cause the following IF check to fail even when no lines are inserted

  IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    BREAK
  END

END
```

But the issue is, after any operation even when no more rows fit my `some_condition`, `@@ROWCOUNT` is equal to `1`, not `0`.

How can I break that loop when there are 0 rows returned matching my `some_condition`?

Comment: When you say this is "simplified", could your actual code have anything in between the INSERT and the test of @@ROWCOUNT that might have set the @@ROWCOUNT value?  It might be safest to capture the @@ROWCOUNT value in an int variable immediately after the INSERT and use that variable in your test.  I'm not sure about Sybase, but in SQL Server SET ROWCOUNT has been deprecated and it's recommended to use SELECT TOP (100)...

Comment: The code you posted has one BEGIN and two ENDs, so the IF and the BREAK are outside of your WHILE loop. How about posting code that works?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Implemented solution similar to Moho, but used `SELECT` instead of `SET` to store `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: `set @var = something` is the same as `select @var = something`

Comment: also, i'd appreciate the answer and upvote as it was my solution ;)

Comment: @Moho, Maybe it is, but I don't get the same results.

Comment: You should have accepted the other answer, or explained exactly what the difference between them was, and what went wrong with the other one. It looks like you just didn't understand Moho's or typed it in wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The "set" statement creates a row count of 1.  What you should do is immediately save @@ROWCOUNT into a @rowCount variable and use that var later on.

```
declare @rowCount int

WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition
  -- EDIT: Realized forgot to include this following vital line that is causing issue
  SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
  SET @var = @var + @rowCount    

  -- @@ROWCOUNT now takes on a value of 1, which will cause the following IF check to fail even when no lines are inserted

  IF(@rowCount = 0)
  BEGIN
    BREAK
  END

END
```

Also, you can simplify by setting @rowCount to -1 initially and changing the WHILE condition to @rowCount <> 0.  The conditional BREAK will no longer be needed.

Comment: For some reason, if I store @@ROWCOUNT into another variable, then that variable will always take a value of 1. I think the `SET` statement is to blame.

Comment: in this example, if @rowCount is 1, then one record has been inserted into table1.  No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. This checks each iteration to see if the ID of the last inserted record has changed or not. If it hasn't changed, it indicates that no records were added that iteration.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 100
declare @id int;
WHILE(1=1)

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition

  IF(@id= @@identity)
  BEGIN
    BREAK
  END
  set @id = @@identity;
END
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand that at all. You have `SET @ID = @@IDENTITY` but you check for `@ID = @@IDENTITY`? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions:

**1st solution**

Using `@@ROWCOUNT` in loop's condition.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 100

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition  


WHILE(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition  

END
```

**2nd solition**

Using `goto`.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 100

WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition

  IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    goto label
  END

END

label1:
print 'After lopp'
```

Comment: Hi Parado, I am currently using something similar to your second solution, but the issue is `@@ROWCOUNT` will not be `0` after the delete condition, it will instead have a value of `1`.

Comment: @czchlong I don't see `delete` statement in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `insert` statement.

Comment: You want to brake a loop after insert one row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `select` to get the `@@rowcount` into a variable. try this:

```
declare @number_of_rows int    

SET ROWCOUNT 100

WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE some_condition

  SELECT @number_of_rows=@@ROWCOUNT

  IF (@number_of_rows = 0)
  BEGIN
     BREAK
  END
END
```

Comment: Hi Ofir thanks for answer. I just realized I missed a vital line after my `insert` statement that I am sure that setting `@@ROWCOUNT` to `1`.